# append() is not a function jQuery in ajax data srting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I get a "Uncaught TypeError: dataString.append is not a function" when i tried to append a file data to ajax data string.

So here is my code

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload">
```

Ajax:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var address1 = document.getElementById("address").value;
var dataString = '&name=' + name +
                 '&address1=' + address1 ;
var fuData = document.getElementById('upload');
var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;
if (FileUploadPath == '') {
           alert("Please upload an image");                                         
 } else {
dataString.append( "upload", $("#upload")[0].files[0]);
   }
$.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: ".../upload.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) {
              var pkg = JSON.parse(data);
              if (pkg.status) {
                  var rs_items = pkg.result_data;
                  //var msg = pkg.quote;
                  // alert(pkg.result_data);
                  alert('saved');
                 //('#msg').html(msg);
              } else {
                   //alert(pkg.msg);
               }
             }
  });
```

If some one can suggest a better way to send specific form data with a image upload to a PHP,it would be a great help.

Comment: are you trying ajax file upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData) for this purpose :

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('upload', $("#upload")[0].files[0]); 

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '.../upload.php',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
})
```

Comment: can i join "dataString" to formData using the same method that you have given  ?

Comment: You can specify exact data in FormData `formData.append('dataString', 'mystring');`

Comment: So basically "append" can be only used with  "HTML DOM" objects.and thanks for the help